# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of laun

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Hi I just followed up the code from Udemy class but I got a problem when I opened Heroku.
I am a newbie here I hope anybody can help me out

Index.js

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ hi: 'there' });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(5000);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.2",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Error

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch


at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-cliffs-96699.herokuapp.com request_id=ea43a5f3-75e7-4815-a059-a62d486c79f4 fwd="69.157.0.58" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(5000);
```

You are not listening to the variable `PORT`. You are always listening on `5000`. Bind to the `PORT`.

Comment: Then what should i modify with that

Comment: Change `app.listen(5000);` to `app.listen(PORT);`

Answer (score 0):

i have been facing the same problem I followed the above solution and redeployed app again from scratch on Heroku this solved my problem
and also this video is super helpful too
https://youtu.be/MxfxiR8TVNU

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.